# Why do we regard $z$ and $\bar z$ as independent in CFT?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, complex-numbers

I have been studying String Theory and CFT for a while, and I am sad to say I do not know why we treat $z$ and $\bar z$ as independent variables, and why we go on to consider the algebra $Vir\oplus\bar {Vir}$ instead of simply $Vir$. The literature I followed never really explained this, just simply did it. Is there a clear explanation of this fact?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116992/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51923/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why treat complex scalar field and its complex conjugate as two different fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/)

Comment: An arbitrary complex number has two components.  Treating  z and z¯ independently in effect allows the two components to be varied separately.

Comment: Not really a duplicate imho: the other questions do not mention the symmetry algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity let us consider global conformal symmetry rather than the full Virasoro symmetry. Global symmetry corresponds to the group $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ acting on $z$ as $z\to \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. So far $\bar z$ is the complex conjugate of $z$, not independent.

In a quantum theory we want the symmetry algebra to act on a complex space of states, not just on the geometry. So we have to complexify the symmetry algebra. In two dimensions, it turns out that the complexified symmetry algebra factorizes,
$$
sl(2,\mathbb{C})^\mathbb{C} = sl(2,\mathbb{C}) \oplus sl(2,\mathbb{C})
$$
The two factors lead to Ward identities that involve $z$ and $\bar z$ independently: this can be interpreted as $z$ and $\bar z$ becoming independent. But this independence only holds at the level of Ward identities. Physical quantities (such as correlation functions) are functions of $z\in \mathbb{C}$, not $(z,\bar z)\in\mathbb{C}^2$.

For more details along these lines, see my review article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290 .

Comment: Note that it is only in Euclidean signature that $z=\bar z^*$. For example, in Lorentzian signature $z$ and $\bar z$ are real and independent. More generally, correlators are analytic functions of independent complex $z$ and $\bar z$ and interpolate between Euclidean and Lorentzian correlators, although they are only known to be analytic in certain subsets of $\mathbb{C}^2$.